# imread from scipy.misc does not work on pycharm. I can't seem to install PIL either

Tags: python, pycharm, imread

`from scipy.misc import imread`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'imread'`

If I run the first on pycharm, I get the following message. I've came across that I need to install PIL or Pillow to work with `imread`. However, trying to install PIL on pycharm gives me this warning.

[warning I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhVBc.png)

+) interpreter that I'm running on pycharm is:
`'/Users/jeongseohyeong/anaconda3/envs/DL/bin/python'` (python 3.6)

I've also seen posts that are saying `pip install pil` works. However, it doesn't seem to work for me (or at least it works for my jupyter notebook which is built in `'/Users/jeongseohyeong/anaconda3/bin/python'`). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Imread has been depreciated.  Either roll back to scipy 1.1 so you can use it or use another module.